# Apply the html name attribute to a form when the html controls are buried in components

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms

I'm struggling with applying template driven form syntax in angular 2, to my own form.

These 2 basic html attributes in particular:

> 1) Use ngModel to bind the model to form control. The binding can be
>   either one way or two way. In our case, we enable two way binding with
>   banana in a box syntax [()].
>
> 2) Use name attribute to register a form
>   control with the form. E.g. we assign "name" to the name attribute,
>   then when we retrieve the name field from form value (f.value).

How do I set the name of form values (the model properties) of my form if the forms html controls are buried in components?

EG I don't have html elements in my form, they're buried in components. EG my form has this:

```
        <div class="form-item-container btn-group">
            <my-area #areaInput (onAreaChanged)="onAreaChanged($event)">
            </my-area>
        </div>
```

Where can I set name in html which will add a name property to the model (data/value) of my form?

EG how can I do this:

```
<input type="text"
                name="street" [(ngModel)]="user.address.street"
                #street="ngModel" required>
```

on, this:

```
    <div class="form-item-container btn-group">
        <my-area #areaInput (onAreaChanged)="onAreaChanged($event)">
        </my-area>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'd assume these elements already have a `name` attribute. I don't really understand the question. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I think you need to do it in the source of the buried element. If it doesn't have it, it's probably not supposed to be used this way.

Comment: If `my-area` provides a `ControlValueAccessor` you should just be able to use it with `<my-area [(ngModel)]="..."`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I originally did look into using a `ControlValueAccessor` but the internet article was talking a lot about how if you can instead, use native html elements rather than custom elements it is probably better...and I started to wonder if mine were even custom, since deep down (in the component) they are regular html form elements...I was wondering if "custom" meant something other than an html input that had been made by you to fully replace the input...so the `ControlValueAccessor` is actually the correct path?

Comment: I guess I start to understand what you try to accomplish. I'm sure in your case `ControlValueAccessor` is the right way to make your custom component usable as form control. And yes, "use native html elements rather than custom elements", means you should not start building advanced buttons that are not actually using a `<button>` internally (same with `<input>` because there are many things that are hard or even impossible to get right by implementing all their features yourself (for example based on a `<div>`).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Good to know. Yeah...I'd never even consider replacing the `<button>` etc with something else, mine are just standard html inside the components. I'll use `ControlValueAccessor`. Thanks